# Как ограничить доступ к странице администратора Java?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mvc, java-ee

Пишу веб-сервис с формой авторизации и регистрации. Есть два типа пользователей: обычные и администратор. Есть контроллер, который перекидывает на страницу администратора по заданному URL:

```
@Controller
public class ViewPageController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sendAdminPage(){
        return "AdminPage";
    }
}
```

Но обычные пользователи также могут получить доступ к этой странице. Нужно, чтобы на страницу администратора попадали только те, кто авторизовался как администратор. Есть варианты, как это можно организовать? Может, сохранять вошедшего пользователя в сессии?(Желательно без Spring Security)

Comment: Чем вам Spring Security не угодил?

Comment: Если есть БД, можете проверять в БД наличие куки для админа. Либо, что у вас будет токеном. Можете делать проверку по логин/паролю при переходе на страницу, то есть, сначала должна быть страница авторизации